# Why does a recursive function call need to return a value to calling function?

Tags: c, visual-studio, recursion, return

In the following recursive function,

```
int subtractByOne(int num) {
    printf("%d\n", num);
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    return subtractByOne(num - 1);
}
```

Why is the final return necessary? From what I understand, the base case will always stop the recursion and when control reaches the end of the function (after the recursive call) the function will transfer control to whomever called it without the return.

My knowledge of stack frames and return addresses is weak, but the stack should receive a return address independent of the actual return keyword, no?

Visual Studio 2015 throws a warning about control paths, which I understand. However, during a programming course a grader's IDE would not compile similar code and the professor commented the code was incorrect as opposed to just bad practice. I fixed the code at the time, but never understood why it was incorrect.

Comment: A recursive function call is no different from any other function call.  Suppose instead of calling itself, you had hundreds of identical copies that only differed in that they called the next function in the chain rather than themselves.  The need for returns is obvious in that case, right?  Well, a recursive call is no different.

Comment: Not sure what youm mean here: _"Visual Studio 2015 throws a warning about control paths..."_ your `subtractByOne` function compiles without warnings.

Comment: "the base case will always stop the recursion"? There's no such thing as "stop the recursion". All you can do is return to the previous level of recursion, i.e "backtrack". BTW, backtracking is a crucial property of true recursion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function definition says it will return an integer. If you do not put the last return the only the base case will return the value 0 and transfer the control to the previous (caller) function but no other return will be occur.

You probably do not need the return value in this case, and so you may use void as return in the function definition, and get rid of all the return altogether, however in many case you will need the return. One such simple example is to calculate the sum of 1...n integers as follows:

```
int sum(int n)
{
   if(n==0)
       return 0;
   return n + sum(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example it would work fine. However, the compiler will and should warn you if the function declaration is stating that the function should return the value and the return statement is conditional. The compiler does not know that it will work. However, it sound strange if the compiler threw an error.

It is not strictly necessary with return statements at all just to achieve recursion either. Here is an example.

```
void printNumbers(int a)
{
    if(a > 0) {
        printf("%d\n", a);
        printNumbers(a-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printNumbers(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does a recursive function call need to return a value to calling function?

Short answer: **A recursive function doesn't have to return a value**

All functions - recursive or not - have one or more `return`. The `return` may or may not include a value. It is for you to decide when you write the function. All explicit written `return` statements must return the correct type.

However, it is legal (but bad practice) to leave out the return in the end of the function. But **only if** the return value is **never used**.

So the code below is legal:

```
int subtractByOne(int num) {
    printf("%d\n", num);
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    subtractByOne(num - 1);
}

subtractByOne(42);
```

However, the code below has undefined behavior because the return value is used and the function doesn't return a value in the end of the function:

```
int subtractByOne(int num) {
    printf("%d\n", num);
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    subtractByOne(num - 1);
}

int a;
a = subtractByOne(42);  // Undefined behavior !
printf("%d", a);
```

As you can see the same function can be used in a legal way but also in a way that causes undefined behavior. **So even though it is legal, it is a real bad idea to omit the return statement for non-void functions.** In other words - always include a return statement in non-void functions.

BTW - always compile with a high warning level so that the compiler will tell you if you forgot a return statement.

The failing compiler at your course was probably set to be strict about this and therefore warned you that your code was bad (but not illegal).

A better way to write your function would be to make it a void function:

```
void subtractByOne(int num) {
    printf("%d\n", num);
    if (num == 0)
        return;
    subtractByOne(num - 1);
}
```

Comment: I just spent 15 minutes reading the standard to see that you were indeed right. But. I must say that teaching this little obscure technicality to someone who is clearly a beginner is a bad idea. Especially since it seems to be one of those edge cases where the standard draws a very careful line around bad stuff people were doing for decades. Or it is compatibility with implicit function declarations. New code should always return correct values from functions that aren't void (and people can figure out the nuances to this fundamentalism when they read the standard).

Comment: In case someone is thinking "WTF?" and frantically digging into the standard to find this. It is in C11, 6.9.1, §12.

Comment: @Art I'm not sure what your point is as I repeated several times that even if it is legal to omit the return statement, it is **bad** practice, i.e. don't do it. Anyway - I tried to clarify it even further.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the final return necessary? From what I understand, the base
>   case will always stop the recursion and when control reaches the end
>   of the function (after the recursive call) the function will transfer
>   control to whomever called it without the return.

You designed `subtractByOne` to return an `int` (that's its signature), then you must return a value of type `int` on every call.

> My knowledge of stack frames and return addresses is weak, but the
>   stack should receive a return address independent of the actual return
>   keyword, no?

Yes, return address is "automatically" managed on your behalf, this is why explicitly using `return` is not required to return to the caller, the rule is that is if you just let the instruction flow reach the end of the function block then a return to the caller is emitted. The `return` keyword is used either to return from another point or **send back a value to the caller**.

> practice. I fixed the code at the time, but never understood why it
>   was incorrect.

If you don't show us the incorrect code, then we are not able to explain why it is.

Now,

```
int subtractByOne(int num) {
    printf("%d\n", num);
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    return subtractByOne(num - 1);
}
```

while correct is not very useful, because any call with a positive value will get  0 in return.